# Can't login to CP – form has expired

Tags: control-panel, error, login

So I just migrated from my dev server to the production server and I can see the site and CP login page fine. However, trying to login I get:

**An Error Was Encountered**
This form has expired. Please refresh and try again.

I've Google'd around a bit but can't figure this one out yet. DB, server and browser cache all clear. Anyone had this before?

Comment: I assume you follow all the steps outlined in the ee migration guide right? http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/operations/moving.html

Comment: maybe obvious but have you cleared all cookies? Have you tried setting: $env_config['allow_extensions']     = 'n';
$env_config['user_session_type'] = 's';
$env_config['admin_session_type'] = 's';

Comment: Thanks guys but I'm no further on. Really weird. Host is trying to debug too, and now says they're able to login fine. I still can't though. Cleared caches, closed browser, etc... but still get the error. I might try the migration again in case something was missed.

Comment: Have you checked your Cookie Domain settings?

Comment: Hi. The Cookie Domain, Path and Prefix are all currently blank. I've tried specifying these too (in my config), but no joy.

Comment: We seem to be encountering this issue intermittently on our install after upgrading to 2.8.1. I don't like the option of disabling CSRF protection and we are not using the Cookie Consent Module. We also use 'cookie' only as our session types and don't really want to switch. This feels like a EllisLab bug to me, no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Big thanks to Joel Bradbury for solving this one. I needed to add

```
$config['disable_csrf_protection'] = 'y';
```

to my config. Here's why:

> It'll be because the tokens have been generated on a different base domain, and then it's moved and gotten stuck. Normally they're regenerated when they're detected as expired, but if it see's them as not expired, but invalid it can get confused. The hashes are kept in exp_security_hashes, just emptying that table will do it too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug when the 'Cookie Consent Module' is installed on 2.8. Here are some temporary fixes for now:

- Disable CSRF protection by putting the following line in your config:

  $config['disable_csrf_protection'] = 'y';
- Disable the Cookie Consent Module.
- Try the fix as explained on the Cookie Consent Module GitHub page (https://github.com/EllisLab/Cookie-Consent/issues/2). However, this will still set cookies.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help but the cookie consent module isn't installed :( Also, weirdly it seems you can login using the latest version of Chrome. Shouldn't be a browser issue though surely.