# An Error Was Encountered This form has expired. Please refresh and try again

Tags: control-panel, system

I am getting the above error. Its not a constant error comes and goes. when it happens and i clear cache it seems to "go" but when client tests, the error comes back.

This happens when they upload images to an already existing entry(Image size not the problem, they use small images).

I checked this post out, and it also seemed to be close ([Can't login to CP – form has expired](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/21599/cant-login-to-cp-form-has-expired)), but my question is entries based.

would adding this line in my config.php not affect security: $config['disable_csrf_protection'] = 'y'; and what would this do to my user front-end forms? is this the best solution? what would be the long term fix be for this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

$config['disable_csrf_protection'] = 'y'; is cannot consider as a permanent solution.

CSRF Token is for EE forms security and depends on sessions that will not allow to submit a form if proper CSRF not found. If this error generates in backend forms that are default EE forms, $config['disable_csrf_protection'] = 'y'; is best option.

If this error generates frontend you can simply putbelow code. [Documentation of CSRF Token](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/guidelines/security.html#csrf-tokens-in-templates)

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{csrf_token}">
```

For secure forms with https you need XID: (The XID constant is deprecated starting from 2.8.0)

```
<input type="hidden" name="XID" value="{XID_HASH}">
```